# Grid inside ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, grid, contextmenu

Does anyone know if its possible to get a grid inside a Contextmenu to work? I basically want to layout the menuitems inside a 3x3 grid, but while I can enter the XAML the grid is ignored.

Ta,

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `Grid` to your `Context Menu` by adding `ItemTemplete` for your `Context Menu` like below

```
           <ContextMenu>
               <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                          //your Controls here
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            </ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

3x3 grid inside ContextMenu

```
        <ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <MenuItem Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Header="1111" />
                        <MenuItem Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Header="2222" />
                        <MenuItem Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Header="3333" />
                        <MenuItem Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Header="1111" />
                        <MenuItem Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Header="2222" />
                        <MenuItem Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  Header="3333" />
                        <MenuItem Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Header="1111" />
                        <MenuItem Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Header="2222" />
                        <MenuItem Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Header="3333" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ContextMenu.Template>
        </ContextMenu>
```